# How to Cramer-Rao inequality?

Tags: statistics, education

I am trying to do this function:
$$f(x\mid\theta)=\theta x^{\theta-1}, \;\;0<x<1,\,\,0<\theta<\infty.$$
I have finished finding my MLE.

$$L(x,\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n \theta x_i^{\theta-1} = \theta^n \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\theta-1}$$
$$\log L(x,\theta) = n\log(\theta) + (\theta-1)\sum_{i=1}^n \log(x_i)$$
$$\dfrac{n}{\theta} + \sum_{i=1}^n\log(x_i) = 0$$

So that
$$\hat{\theta} = \dfrac{-n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \log(x_i)}.$$

Please show me how to find Cramer-Rao.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your likelihood function is
$$
L(x,\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^N \theta x_i^{\theta-1} = \theta^N \prod_{i=1}^N x_i^{\theta-1}
$$
and the log likelihood is
$$
\log L(x,\theta) = N\log(\theta) +\sum_{i=1}^N (\theta-1) \log(x_i)
$$
and your MLE solves the first-order condition for the log likelihood,
$$
\dfrac{N}{\theta} + \sum_{i=1}^N\log(x_i) = 0
$$
or
$$
\hat{\theta} = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^N \log(x_i)}{N}.
$$

Now, the information matrix is
$$
I(\theta_0) = -N \mathbb{E}_x[D_\theta^2 \log L(x,\theta_0)] = -N \mathbb{E}_x[-N/\theta_0^2] = N^2/\theta_0^2.
$$

The cramer-rao inequality is that
$$
\text{var}(\hat{\theta}) \ge \dfrac{1}{I(\theta_0)} = \dfrac{\theta_0^2}{N^2},
$$
so the variance of your estimator is bounded by the inverse of the information matrix.

Comment: Please don't provide detailed answers to half-baked questions like these. Especially if it is phrased as homework.

Comment: @StubbornAtom It staves off boredom for me during the coronavirus lockdown to remember all kinds of math I don't regularly use but once knew pretty well, and answering questions for some feckless undergrad will probably help them get that C+ they are hoping for. I think you can avoid these posts easily from their incomprehensible titles, especially given that "cramer-rao inequality" is not a verb.