# How to find Cramer-Rao inequality

Tags: statistics, education

I trying to do this function.
$$f(x\mid\theta)=\theta x^{\theta-1}, \;\;0<x<1,\,\,0<\theta<\infty.$$
I have finished finding my MLE.

$$L(x,\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n \theta x_i^{\theta-1} = \theta^n \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\theta-1}$$
$$\log L(x,\theta) = n\log(\theta) + (\theta-1)\sum_{i=1}^n \log(x_i)$$
$$\dfrac{n}{\theta} + \sum_{i=1}^n\log(x_i) = 0$$
So that
$$\hat{\theta} = \dfrac{-n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \log(x_i)}.$$
So I want everyone to help guide how to find Cramer-Rao?

Comment: You had already accepted the answer in your [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3608016/321264) of this same question. Why are you asking this again?

Answer (score 1):

The variance of any unbiased estimator of $\theta$ is at least as big as the asymptotic variance of $\hat{\theta}$, i.e. $I(\theta)^{-1}$ (this is the Cramer-Rao bound, where $I$ is the fisher information). Here
$$
I(\theta)=-E(\ell''(\theta))=n/\theta^2
$$
where $\ell=\log L$ is the log-likelihood. Hence the Cramer Rao bound is $\theta^2/n$.